# Automatically delete outdated rows from database every n seconds

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-web-services

I have a database which has a timestamp column and I want outdated data to be deleted.

So my idea is to write a MySQL query to a .php file which deletes every row where `timestamp < current_timestamp - const`. As there will be a lot of rows where this has to be checked, I am going to set an index to the timestamp column.

So how can I run this script automatically every n seconds? I heard about Linux crontab - can I use this on my webserver (not the db server) to execute the .php file periodically and is this overall a good technique to delete outdated rows from a database?

The database is set on a RDS instance on Amazon Web Services. My webserver is a EC2 instance (also Amazon Web Services).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing such a thing requires setting up an event or job.  Such efforts keep the database very busy.

I would strongly recommend a different approach.  Use a view to access the data you want:

```
create view v_t as
    select t.*
    from t
    where timestamp > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - ??;
```

Then use this view to access the data.

Then, periodically, go in an clean the table to get rid of the rows that you don't don't want.  You can do this once a day, once a week, once an hour -- the deletions can occur at times when the database load is lighter, so it doesn't affect users.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should check out lambda service on AWS.
It allows you to run commands against AWS services without another instance running.

Here's an example on how to set it up.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc-rds-deployment-pkg.html

Good luck
Eugene

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Linoff's approach is ideal, but if you want to go the route of scheduled jobs, MySQL Event Scheduler is something you can try.  The following example, runs daily and delete records older than a week.

```
CREATE EVENT
  clean_my_table
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
DO
  DELETE FROM my_table
  WHERE time_stamp < date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK);
```

MySQL Event Reference page
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html